# How to add html content with another html content using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
var productInfo= $('#product-info'+PID).html();  
console.log(productInfo); // this works fine
        var pinfoID='padded-info'+PID; // this is okay
```

now I want to wrap product info as follows:

```
   productInfo='<li id="'+pinfoID+'">
                          <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <button type="button" class="close" >×</button>
                            <strong>'+productInfo+'</strong> 
                        </div>
                 </li>';
```

But it does not works. What is wrong am I doing?

Comment: Can you should your full code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appear to be redefining `productInfo` ? Try providing different variable name to final `html` fragment

```
   var productInfoHtml = '<li id=' + pinfoID + '>'
                          + '<div class=alert alert-success>'
                          + '<button type=button class=close>×</button>'
                          + '<strong>' + productInfo + '</strong>' 
                          + '</div></li>';
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL near '<li id="'+pinfoID+'">